# How to compare localized strings in Smalltalk?

Tags: string-comparison, smalltalk, pharo

Is it possible to compare localized strings in some Smalltalk implementation? The only one I have met so far is Pharo and GNU ST, which seem to lack this ability. It seems the only possibility would be to write an [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) wrapper from scratch. (That's far beyond my experiences.)

I know this is a complicated functionality. Unfortunately, it is needed very often everywhere, e.g., sorting menus in web apps.

I mean:

```
'á' > 'a' => true
```

And the possibility to use the comparison for sorting arrays of strings:

```
#('č' 'ř' 'a' 'r' 'á') asSortedCollection => #('a' 'á' 'č' 'r' 'ř')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be straightforward to translate from the NativeBoost (old FFI style used in Pharo 4) to UFFI. The code is [on the gemstone repo](http://ss3.gemstone.com/ss/ICU.html). Easiest way is to
first make sure you can run an old Pharo 4 using deprecated releases in the Launcher and verify that works for you. You might need to install 32-bit libraries for that to work (or use something like a 32-bit virtual box image). The packages independent from NativeBoost load in Pharo 8. There is a [booklet](https://github.com/SquareBracketAssociates/Booklet-uFFI/releases) about UFFI

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't find the 4.0 VM. In any way, it would be really great to have this ability integrated as a matter of course in the basic image. For dynamic web apps in non-English languages, one stumbles upon this need very very quickly.

Comment: To easily load, you'll need an even earlier Pharo: 2.0 You can find it in the same place

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak for other dialects, but [GemStone](https://gemtalksystems.com/products/gs64/) does have this capability:

```
topaz 1> run
'á' > 'a'
%
true
topaz 1> run
#('č' 'ř' 'a' 'r' 'á') asSortedCollection printString
%
aSortedCollection( 'a', 'á', '\u010d', 'r', '\u0159')
topaz 1>
```

For details see the [Programmer's Guide](https://downloads.gemtalksystems.com/docs/GemStone64/3.6.x/GS64-ProgGuide-3.6/5-Strings.htm#pgfId-522313).

Answer (score 2):

I can speak for [Smalltalk/X-jv branch](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/smalltalkx/info) dialect.  If I remember correctly Smalltalk/X is natively Unicode.

Your examples will naturally give your results.  This is direct paste from `Workspace` (adding a space between printed value for better readability):

```
'á' > 'a' true.

#('č' 'ř' 'a' 'r' 'á') asSortedCollection SortedCollection('a' 'r' 'á' 'č' 'ř')
```